# Random seed gives the same value when importing Salabim

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I am trying to generate a random seed with the package `random`. However, I keep getting the same value every time I run the code. I saw that if I don't import `salabim` then the seed generated is always a different number.

This is my code:

```
import salabim as sim  # Without this import the seed generated is always different
import random

RandomSeed = True

#Random Seed
if RandomSeed:
    seed = random.randint(1000000, 9999999) #Random number of 7 digits
    randomstream = random.Random(seed)
else:
    randomstream = None

print(seed)
```

Does anyone know what is causing this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Presumably `salabim` is calling [`random.seed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.seed), causing *your* call to `randint` to no longer be random.

Comment: From the salabim docs: "When a new environment is created, the random seed 1234567 will be set by default".  Presumably this is done to make its simulations deterministic.

Comment: Using RNG to generate a seed seems like a bad idea, since that RNG depends on *its own* seed.  (In other words, in order to generate a seed, you must already have a valid seed, so why not just use the original seed instead of generating a new one?)  Seeds should come from something out-of-band.

Comment: @jasonharper You are right! thanks a lot that helped me understanding the mistake

Answer (score 0):

Best to check the [documentation about the random_seed](https://www.salabim.org/manual/Reference.html#salabim.random_seed).
Seems to me that salabim sets the seed to 1234567, see [salabim.environment](https://www.salabim.org/manual/Reference.html#environment)

I tested with the following code (so adding explictly sim.random_seed) and the printed seed stays the same, being 8259584

```
import salabim as sim  # Without this import the seed generated is always different
sim.random_seed(1234567)  
import random
```